Double-checking my formula derivation
The formula for the surface area of a right antiprism with regular n-gonal bases B isn't on the wikipedia page for antiprisms so I derived it myself.  Based on the diagram below

I got that Surface Area = 2B + 2n$\bigl(\frac{1}{2}sh\bigr)$ = 2B + $shn$.  Just making sure that this can generalize to all such right antiprisms and that I'm not missing anything?  Is the height of the triangle actually a slant height?

https://vixra.org/pdf/2305.0150v1.pdf could be interesting to look at

Let $0\le z \le h$ be the Cartesian coordinate along the long extruded edge. On the base $z=0$ the vertices of the $n$-gon
are at $x_k(0)+iy_k(0)=re^{i 2\pi k/n}$ in complex notation, $k=0..n-1$, $x_k(0)=\cos(2\pi k/n)$, $y_k(0)=\sin(2\pi k/n)$.
The radius $r$ of the $n$-gon circumcircle is related to the side length $s$ as in eq (5) of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6293,
$r=s/[2\sin(\pi/n)]$. In the intermediate region a slice at constant $z$ is a $2n$-gon with 2 different, alternating side lengths.
The coordinates of the $n$ gon at the top, $z=h$,
are $x_k(h)+iy_k(h)=re^{2\pi i (k+1/2)/n}$, rotated relative to the base by half an edge.
The straight line that connects $(x_k(0),y_k(0),0)$ on the base plate to $(x_k(h),y_k(h),h)$ on the top plate
has the coordinates
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_k(z) \\ y_k(z) \\ z\end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c}x_k(0)\\y_k(0)\\0\end{array}\right)+z/h \left(\begin{array}{c}x_k(h)-x_k(0)\\y_k(h)-y_k(0)\\h\end{array}
\right)
$$, straight line/edge along a vector.
The straight line that connects $(x_{k+1}(0),y_{k+1}(0),0)$ on the base plate to $(x_k(h),y_k(h),h)$ on the top plate
has the coordinates
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_k'(z) \\ y_k'(z) \\ z\end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c}x_{k+1}(0)\\y_{k+1}(0)\\0\end{array}\right)+z/h \left(\begin{array}{c}x_k(h)-x_{k+1}(0)\\y_k(h)-y_{k+1}(0)\\h\end{array}
\right)
$$.
The sum of the squares is the squared radius of the circumcircle
$$
x_k(z)^2+y_k(z)^2
=
x_k'(z)^2+y_k'(z)^2
= r(z)^2 = \frac{r^2}{h^2}(2z^2+h^2-2hz+(2z^2-2hz)\cos(\pi/n))
$$
which means the radius of the circumcircle shrinks to some minimum at $z=h/2$.
$r(z)$ is the also one of the side lengths of the $2n$ horizontal triangles at altitude $z$.
The other side length of $n$ of these triangles is the Euclidean distance
between $(x_k(z),y_k(z),z)$ and $x_k'(z),y_k'(z),z)$, which is
$$
s_1(z)^2=[x_k(z)-x_k'(z)]^2 +[y_k(z)-y_k'(z)]^2
=\frac{4r^2(z-h)^2}{h^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}.
$$
$$
s_1(z)
=\frac{2r(h-z)}{h}\sin\frac{\pi}{n}.
$$
Integrating this over $z$ gives the area of one of the slanted triangles of the outer surface,
and the total area is $2n$ times that,
$$
2n\int_0^h \frac{2r(h-z)}{h}\sin\frac{\pi}{n} dz = 2nrh\sin\frac{\pi}{n}=nsh.
$$
One can check that for $n\to \infty$ the base becomes a circle and the surface becomes $2rh\pi$, the
surface of the cylinder of height $h$.
To get also the area of the top and base cap, one must add $2B$, and this gives the same answer
as the one contained in the question.
Postscriptum:
The straight line that connects $(x_{k+1}(0),y_{k+1}(0),0)$ on the base plate to $(x_{k+1}(h),y_{k+1}(h),h)$ on the top plate
has the coordinates
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_k''(z) \\ y_k''(z) \\ z\end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{c}x_{k+1}(0)\\y_{k+1}(0)\\0\end{array}\right)+z/h \left(\begin{array}{c}x_{k+2}(h)-x_{k+1}(0)\\y_{k+2}(h)-y_{k+1}(0)\\h\end{array}
\right)
$$.
The other side length of $n$ of these horizontal triangles is the Euclidean distance
between $(x_k'(z),y_k'(z),z)$ and $x_k''(z),y_k''(z),z)$, which is
$$
s_2(z)^2=[x_k'(z)-x_k''(z)]^2 +[y_k'(z)-y_k''(z)]^2
=\frac{4r^2 z^2}{h^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}.
$$
The semiperimeters of the two types of triangles are
$$
p_i=\frac12(2r(z)+s_i(z)), \quad i=1,2.
$$
By Herons formula the area of the $2n$ horizontal triangles are
$$
A_i = \sqrt{p_i(p_i-r)^2(p_i-s_i)}, \quad i=1,2
$$
$$
A_1 = \frac{r^2}{h^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{n}(h-z)[z+(h-z)\cos\frac{\pi}{n}];
$$
$$
A_2 = \frac{r^2}{h^2}\sin\frac{\pi}{n}z[h-z+z\cos\frac{\pi}{n}];
$$
The area at altitude z is
$$
A(z) = nA_1(z)+nA_2(z) = n\frac{r^2}{h^2} \sin\frac{\pi}{n}[2hz-2z^2+(h^2-2zh+2z^2)\cos\frac{\pi}{n}].
$$
$$
B=A(z=0) =
nr^2 \sin\frac{\pi}{n}\cos\frac{\pi}{n}.
$$
The volume of the antiprism is given by integrating over $z$,
$$
\int_{0}^h n\frac{r^2}{h^2} \sin\frac{\pi}{n}[2hz-2z^2+(h^2-2zh+2z^2)\cos\frac{\pi}{n}] dz
=\frac13 nr^2h\sin\frac{\pi}{n}[1+2\cos\frac{\pi}{n}].
$$
